# Angular, PieChart, NodeJS and multiple queries

Tags: sql, angularjs, node.js, devextreme

I'm trying set my second query to the pie chart datasource in angular and nodejs using multiple queries to get the results at same time
Someone have some idea to solve it.

## Server Side

```
var url = require('url');
//Require express, 
var express = require('express');
//and create an app
var app = express();


var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    multipleStatements: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'hello',
    password: 'passw',
    database: 'db',
    port: 330333
});


//var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});

app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});


app.get('/sts', function (req, res) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, \n\
//                    GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');


      connection.query(   
            " SELECT ST.manufacturer, ST.name, ST.model, ST.os, ST.status, " +
            " SI.Coord, ST.Last_Update_Date_Time FROM " +
            " ( " +
            " select s.manufacturer, s.name, s.model, s.os, s. status,  " +
            "   concat(DATE(s.last_update_date),' ',TIME(s.last_update_time)) as Last_Update_Date_Time " +
            " from sts s " +
            " order by Last_Update_Date_Time DESC " +
            " ) AS ST   JOIN " +
            " ( " +
            " select DISTINCT CONCAT(si.latitude, ', ',  si.longitude) as Coord, " +
            "       concat(DATE(update_date),' ',TIME(update_time)) as Update_Date_Time " +
            " from sts_info si " +
            " order by Update_Date_Time DESC " +
            " ) AS SI ON ST.Last_Update_Date_Time = SI.Update_Date_Time; " +
            " " +
            "   \n\  " +
            "       SELECT ST.manufacturer, ST.name, ST.model, ST.os, ST.status, " +
            "       count(status) as CountStatus,  " +
            "            SI.Coord, ST.Last_Update_Date_Time FROM   " +
            "        (   " + 
            "        select s.manufacturer, s.name, s.model, s.os, s. status,   " +
            "          concat(DATE(s.last_update_date),' ',TIME(s.last_update_time)) as Last_Update_Date_Time   " +
            "        from sts s   " +
            "        order by Last_Update_Date_Time DESC  " +
            "         ) AS ST   JOIN    " +
            "        (  " + 
            "        select DISTINCT CONCAT(si.latitude, ', ',  si.longitude) as Coord,  " +
            "              concat(DATE(update_date),' ',TIME(update_time)) as Update_Date_Time  " +
            "        from sts_info si  " +
            "        order by Update_Date_Time DESC  " +
            "         ) AS SI ON ST.Last_Update_Date_Time = SI.Update_Date_Time     " +
            "         group by status; "





        , function (err, rows) {    




        if (!err) {
            console.log("Database is connected... \n");
            console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0]);
            console.log('The solution is: ', rows[1]);

        } else {
            console.log("Error connecting database... \n");
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        }
        console.log(rows[0]);
        console.log(rows[1]);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows[1]));

    });


});


var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    var host = server.address().address;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

## AngularJs

---

```
    **$scope.chartOpt1 = {
            bindingOptions: {
                dataSource: "sts"

            },**
```

---

```
//Exposes the current URL in the browser address bar
//Maintains synchronization between itself and the browser's URL
//Represents the URL object as a set of methods
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                controller: 'contactController'
            })


            .when('/devicessts', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/devicessts.html',
                controller: 'devicesController'
            })

            .when('/sts', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/sts.html',
                controller: 'stsController'
            });


//  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

The result of the page:

[image]

Look at the data grid and pie chart aren't being showed in the page.

How do I retrieve the results from query to the angular?

Thank you

Comment: You posted too much code, can you simplify it pls ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want get 2 responses you should :

- post 2 request
  OR
- replace this

  ```
  res.end(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
  res.end(JSON.stringify(rows[1]));
  ```

by this

```
    res.end(JSON.stringify([rows[0],rows[1]]));
```

But a single http request can't send 2 responses

Comment: Ok. That's it!  But How Can I send 2 responses at same time? That way didn't work yet.    
      res.end(JSON.stringify([rows[0],rows[1]]));

Comment: How do I handle from Angular side?
**$scope.chartOpt1 = {
            bindingOptions: {
                dataSource: "sts"

            },**